# How to do a Sagepay Server inFrame integration?

Tags: php, mysql, opayo

I tried all the tutorials but I found I was not able to integrate using Sagepay server inframe integration.

Comment: Can you post the code that you gave already tried and failed with?

Comment: thanks for reply. actually i got only direct integration codes which worked all well for me but I need to integrate the inframe method, in which a credit card validation form from sagepay server is shown in frame in my website. but i cant get the idea how and from where to get that form. thats the main problm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on the SagePay website is very good, generally you will need to create a class that can generate a some strings that are in the correct format and use curl to fire it over to sagepay then create a script to handle the response. If you have not already done so, create yourself a simulator account with SagePay so you can debug your script this is a seriously useful feature and makes developing with SagePay easier than with RBS WorldPay for example.

Just get stuck in to it and if you have any specific questions when you have had a go, let me know.

Comment: yes the documentation worked very well for me but i didnt get any documentation regarding how to use server inframe method of sagepay and that where I am stucked :(

Comment: When you post your initial string to sagepay with curl, you will get a response back. One of these reponses will be $_POST['NextURL'], use this url as the src attribute of your iframe.

Comment: Exactamondo, if the data you posted to sagepay is correct then the response will contain the url to go to the card selection page which is displayed in your iframe.

Comment: but when i used that NextURL attribute as src for iframe it took me to simulator account page. I went on all the Proceed buttons but nowhere the card selection came up :( . Can u help me out with some codes please... :)

Comment: Thats because you are linking to a simulator account! If you are reaching this then everything is ok, switch to a test account to see the card selection page, as this never appears on the simulator page. You are doing it correctly.

Comment: one thing, its being pointed to https://test.sagepay.com/simulator/........ should it be pointing to something like https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/......., is it????

Comment: The second url is for the test account and the first for the simulator. Note: with test accounts you must be running the script on a server that has it's IP address whitelisted on your test account otherwise it will fail with 'Invalid IP Address'

Comment: which one should i be using simulator or gateway one??? are both account free to create???

Comment: Use the simulator account for testing. The test account is part of the main account so will only be accessable when you create an actual functioning SagePay account linked to your [client's] bank account. Simulator was designed for developers to be able to debug their code without needing a full account.

Comment: yes i understood that. On simulator account everything works fine but I need to create the payment in inframe system of Sagepay, So, I think for that i will require that gateway test server access ya???

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. But if your code works ok in the simulator it will work in real life. When you or your client has a full account then just change the sagepay url in your code to be the test/live url and job done problem solved.

Comment: Then without getting a gateway testing server we cant use the card selection feature and inframe feature, m I right??? :-D

Comment: Of course!! How do you expect to take payment on your site without having an account! Simulator account is free because its for developers, why are you obsessed with seeing the card selection page, if your code works in the simulator, it works. If you want to start recieveing payment, you need an account, or your client, if you are working for somebody else needs an account, which is verified and approved by SagePay.

Comment: well I am doing this for one of my client. Simulator one works perfect and I think I will need to ask my client to create a Account on sagepay so I can test for inframe method also. Thanks for you great help. Really Appreciate you help. You rock :)

Comment: i was asked to make in inframe method with card procedures so i asked. thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, like myself who has been searching and searching for an example of inframe I did find one on github here: https://github.com/swicks/sagepay-server-for-woocommerce

there's a few things you need to change. The call back uses the old api I think

So instead of: $this->notification_url         = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', add_query_arg( 'wc-api', 'DS_Sagepay_Server', home_url( '/' ) ) );

should be: $this->notification_url = get_site_url() . '/wc-api/DS_Sagepay_Server

Also I had to change all the shipping_ to billing_ but that just be my set-up as I don't have shipping...

Comment: Thats seems to be removed from github. Do you have a copy by any chance you could upload