# Sagepay Server & iFrame integration

Tags: php, iframe, opayo

I realise there is quite a bit on this in other posts and i am getting my teeth into those too, but i just want to clear one fundamental point up before i get into detail.

I have read in depth the integration document and i understand the principles.  The iFrame is a corollary of server integration with a couple additions to the communication with the Sage server as i understand it; but that is for later.  What i am completely stumped by is this php downloadable integration kit.

The document states that we just need to issue some value name pairs and I feel completely happy with that.  The document also states that there are examples of the posts and the notificationURL reply posts that are needed in the integration kit.

In the integration kit i find two directories: demo and lib.  Following the instructions to integrate the SQL into my dev environment I can get the demo to work.  I can use it to make a purchase from their CD shop, but the calls and code to initialise the Sage are buried all around a really really complicated directory structure with loads of includes and external calls to throw you off the scent.  I have looked atlots of the files and nowhere do i see any name/value pairs being passed.  In the lib directory are a config file, and a constants file with lots of variable declarations and an initialisation file which presumably starts the whole thing off somehow, but just gives a blank screen in a browser.  There is a folder called classes with many many files defining various classes, but no help files or useful notes.

What there is not is any explanation of what to do or any examples.  So this is my question for anybody who has done this recently:  Do i just need to post some value pairs to the server specified in the documentation (easy peasy), or do i need to have the sage files present on my server and initialise some objects and relevent properties within the class structure in the integration pack etc.  The two are pretty much poles apart for me, particularly without any help files to navigate the classes structure.

Does anybody know which is the correct solution and where the mentioned exmples might be hiding.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you read the answers ( and all the comments ) on this question. I'm finding it helpful myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376428/need-sagepay-server-inframe-integration-help  ... there is also a link to a github example in one answer

Comment: Thanks byron, I have made some progress using other posts.  Most others seem to use value pairs and not the class structure.  This said I think my original question is still remains a mystery to me - ie What's with the integration kit and the absence of instructions.

Comment: I dont know I thought that all payment gateways were like that ... kind of mysterious ... I don't know really.